# Split a string of length n into substrings or length m

Tags: combinatorics

Similar to
[this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412338/in-how-many-ways-can-you-split-a-string-of-length-n-such-that-every-substring-ha) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113057/how-many-substrings-of-length-m-can-be-formed-from-a-string-of-length-n?rq=1). I am interested in determining the number of possibilities that exist for splitting a string of length m into non-overlapping substrings of fixed length m.

As discussed in the first post, the number of valid starting positions is given by n-m+1. I am interested in the total number of resulting substrings of length m.

### Example 1

Take n=7 and m=3. There are in total 5 possible starting positions. The following possibilities exist for a string consisting of random characters ccccccc:

```
ccc|ccc|.
.|ccc|ccc
..|ccc|..
ccc|.|ccc
```

Here | marks the start/end of a new substring, and . marks an unused character.

In total we have N<sub>3</sub> = 7 substrings of length m=3.

### Example 2

Take n=6 and m=3. The following possibilities exist for a string consisting of random characters cccccc:

```
ccc|ccc|
.|ccc|..
..|ccc|.
```

In total we have N<sub>3</sub>=4 substrings of length m=3, which is the same as the number of starting positions.

I am confused as to how to enumerate all resulting substrings, i.e. how to calculate N<sub>m</sub> for a string of length n.

To extent on the subject, ultimately I would like to determine the frequency of substrings of different lengths, i.e. how to calculate N<sub>i</sub>, for i=3,...,M, allowing for all substring lengths at the same time.

### Comment: Bill Liu (Note: Does not give the right result)

Rewriting the recursion expression gives

$f(i-1,l)=f(i,l)+f(i-1+l,l)$.

It works for $l=3$, $n=6$ (example 2). Starting the recursion from $i=n-l+1=4$ gives:

$i=4:  f(3,3)=f(4,3)+f(6,3)=1+1=2$

$i=3:  f(2,3)=f(3,3)+f(5,3)=2+1=3$

$i=2:  f(1,3)=f(2,3)+f(4,3)=3+1=4$

where $f(i,3)=1$ for $i>n-l=3$.

So here $f(1,3)=N_3=4$.

*However*, example 1 ($l=3$, $n=7$) does not give the correct answer. Starting the recursion from $i=n-l+1=5$ gives:

$i=5:  f(4,3)=f(5,3)+f(7,3)=1+1=2$

$i=4:  f(3,3)=f(4,3)+f(6,3)=2+1=3$

$i=3:  f(2,3)=f(3,3)+f(5,3)=3+1=4$

$i=2:  f(1,3)=f(2,3)+f(4,3)=4+2=6$

where $f(i,3)=1$ for $i>n-l=4$.

This is not the correct answer $f(1,3)\neq N_3=7$ (see above).

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking about solving this problem using recursion / dynamic programming:

Let $f(start, l)$ be the number of ways to split the string starting from index $start$, and each sub-string has length $l$.

Then $f(i,l)=1$ for each $i>n-l$ because we need to abandon all characters after it -- only this single way exists;
Otherwise, $f(i,l)=f(i+1,l)+f(i+l,l)$. The prior terms corresponds to when we abandon $i^{th}$ character, and the latter term corresponds to when we grab a sub-string of length $l$ starting from $i^{th}$ character.

The only thing left is the solve the recursion, starting from $i=n$.

Comment: Thanks Liu. Please see my detailed comments in the original post.

Comment: Just to be clear: I agree, recursive programming would be the way to go. However your idea does not give the right result. Any further suggestions?